# eval addition with -1 doesn't work

Tags: jquery, eval

I'm having trouble with this js code:

```
$('.downvoted').live('click',function(){
var ele = $(this);
var truc = ele.prev('.score_position');

$.post('ajax/vote.php', { vote :ele.attr('title') }, function(data) {
    if(data == 'done'){
        ele.removeClass('downvoted').addClass('downvote').html('<img src="images/down.png" />');
        truc.html(eval(truc.html()+1));
    }
});
return false;
});
```

so I have this same function 3 other times for downvoting, un-upvoting and upvoting. It works well except with one exception, if truc.html() is -1 then it goes to -11 instead of 0.

Any idea why it doesn't work? (you guys can try it here: http://91.121.154.130/?sort=last&# with id:azerty pw:azerty)

Comment: :( Why use `eval` when there's a perfectly good [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function?

Comment: @JamesAllardice He is evaluating *after* the addition operation (which doesn't make sense btw). Your comment implies that `eval` can be substituted with `parseInt` here, which also doesn't make sense (those two functions serve different purposes).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Good point. As I think you've assumed, I didn't notice that the `+1` was part of the argument to `eval` too.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: It makes sense.  `parseInt("12"+1, 10)` is `121`, `eval("12"+1)` is also `121`.

Comment: Any idea on this odd eval behavior though?

Comment: @Rocket Yes, using `parseInt` here does make sense. But the comment implied that `eval` can be substituted by `parseInt` which does not make sense. I was referring to that.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Ah, ok.  In this case it makes sense, but not all cases.

Comment: @David天宇Wong The behavior has nothing to do with `eval`. In JavaScript, `'1' + 1` evaluates to `'11'`, since the `+` operator also performs string concatenation. You need to coerce the operands to the Number type before adding them together.

Comment: @David天宇Wong: You're using `+` on a string, which concats strings.  `"12"+1` is `"121"`, not `13`.

Comment: @Rocket it was working for positive values

Comment: @David天宇Wong:  It would only work when it starts at `0`. `"0"+1` is `"01"` which parses to `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `eval()` for this sort of work! Use `parseInt`, `Number(...)`, or any of the other numerous ways of converting a value to a number in Javascript.

```
truc.html(parseInt(truc.html(), 10) + 1);
```

Note the second parameter in the `parseInt` function. This means you want the value passed into be parsed as a base-10 number. If you pass in a number starting with 0 into the `parseInt` function without specifying the radix you'll get an unexpected and unwanted result.

Or

```
truc.html(Number(truc.html())+1);
```

Or even this:

```
truc.html(truc.html()*1 + 1);
```

This works because multiplying a string number by one results converts the variable to a number. Be careful-- if the variable you multiply isn't a valid number you'll get `NaN`!

The reason you can't simply do `truc.html(truc.html()+1);` is because `.html()` returns a string value. If you add a number to a string in Javascript, the number is simply concatenated to the string, and no  math is performed. (e.g. "-1" + "1" equals "-11").

Comment: Don't forget the radix argument to `parseInt`.

Comment: I suggest adding `,10` to the `parseInt`, to make sure the numbers are interpreted as base 10.

Comment: You might also want to move the `+1` outside of the `parseInt`.  This will still make `-11` instead of `0`, like in the question.

Comment: Yes, right, my mistake. That's what comes of writing an answer too fast, I guess.

Comment: I still get the same behavior. You mean parseInt(truc.html()+1,10) right? oupsie, just read your edit, should work now :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Nope, I edited my answer (it was incorrect before). Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Try parsing (never use `eval`) the value to an integer first:

```
truc.html( parseInt( truc.html(), 10 ) + 1 );
```

Keep in mind that `+` also performs string concatenation in JavaScript. If you have a string, '1', and you *add* an integer of 1 to it, it will result in a string of '11'.

Parsing a string to an integer first, and then performing the math, results in your expected outcome.

Comment: @Rocker I never forget my radix ;)

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Thanks, that last one snuck by me somehow.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because the concatentor for javascript is the plus sign `+`, and if parsed as a string a `+` will cause string concatenation, instead of the desired addition. Fix it by making sure JS parses your `truc.html()` as an int by using the `parseInt()` function like so:

```
truc.html( parseInt( truc.html(), 10 ) + 1 );
```

Also not sure why you're using eval in the first place, Elliot has touched upon the issues there..

Answer (score 1):

```
truc.html(parseInt( truc.html(), 10 ) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the value is an integer and Use of `.text()` is better on this case.

```
parseInt(truc.text(), 10)+1
```

Comment: `parseInt` removes the need for `eval`!

Comment: @JamesAllardice, Rushed the answer to soon.

Comment: Don't forget the `,10` in `parseInt`. :-P